# Does http keepalive_timeout also apply to upstream?

Tags: nginx

Given this nginx config:

```
http {
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    upstream nodejs {
        server 127.0.0.1:8088;
    }
    server {
        listen 8080;
        location / {
            proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that the `http.keepalive_timeout` defines the timeout to the client, while an `http.upstream.keepalive_timeout` would define the timeout to the upstream.

Does a `keepalive_timeout` value defined in `http` also implicitly set the `upstream` `keepalive_timeout` when it's not explicitly defined like in the example above, because `upstream` is part of `http`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a chapter regarding inheritance in the [docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/basic-functionality/managing-configuration-files/#inheritance). The answer is "yes", the child context inherits directives of the parent context:

> In general, a child context – one contained within another context
>   (its parent) – inherits the settings of directives included at the
>   parent level. Some directives can appear in multiple contexts, in
>   which case you can override the setting inherited from the parent by
>   including the directive in the child context.